# How to list all children of a tag which shares its name with another sibling in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a list of children tags of a particular tag. The tag is div. However, it has another sibling called div which is 2nd in the list of its siblings.

```
enter code here
     print(len(soup.body.div.main.div.section))
     8

     for i in range(8):
          print(soup.body.div.main.div.section.contents[i].name)

      None
      a
      div
      None
      script
      None
      input
      div

print(soup.body.div.main.div.section.contents[7].name)
div
print(soup.body.div.main.div.section.div)
<div class="front-end-breadcrumb"></div>

print(len(soup.body.div.main.div.section.div))
0
print(len(soup.body.div.main.div.section.contents[2]))
0
print(len(soup.body.div.main.div.section.contents[7]))
2
print(soup.body.div.main.div.section[7])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1016, in __getitem__
return self.attrs[key]
 KeyError: 7
```

What I want is to be able to get the length of the second div tag. By usin...contents[7] I was able to find the length. However, I may not always know where there second div tag is in the list of children of section.

I would like to be able to get a list of all children tags of the second div tag in the above code.

Also if second div has child main then I want to be able to call contents.div[2].main. However it doesn't work because of the keyerror. What is a workaround for it.

This is the webpage I am working on:

https://www.indiatoday.in/magazine/cover-story/story/20071231-a-lost-cause-734888-2007-12-21

There is a lot of html content so I don't think I can post everything.

Comment: What determines the "particular tag" whose children you want?  For example, is it necessarily the first div within a particular object?  Or maybe a div of a particular class?  A div containing a certain bit of text?  Something else?  Could you post the HTML you're trying to pick this out of?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I have reformatted the code.

Comment: Hi Bill, I have posted the link to the webpage I am working on. I am trying to get the text of the article on this particular page. However, it is only for learning purposes. In this case the particular tag is based on the body of the article. But my question is more general in nature. I am looking to get a list of all the children of the second div. Based on the fact that it is the second of two div siblings. No other consideration. I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using "non-standard" way to select the element, if the DOM tree changed it will fail. Use `find()`, `findAll()`, `select()`, `select_one()` or read the [Docs here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

`contents.div[2].main` is not valid because `contents` is a list **not** DOM tree.

You want to select `<div class="story-section">` and all `div` inside it?

```
# select first element
story_section = soup.find('div', class_='story-section')
# or
story_section= soup.select_one('div.story-section')
print(story_section)

# get all "div" inside ".story-section"
div_in_aricle = story_section.findAll('div')
for div in story_section:
    print(div)

#To get article body
article = soup.select_one('div.description')
# or
article = soup.find('div', class_='description')
print(article.text)
# 60 REVOLUTIONS — KHALISTAN(from left) Kanwar Pal, Zaffarwal,.....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code works for this purpose. I am trying to learn it and looks like I picked the wrong approach. I will go back to documentation then.

Comment: welcome, it is solved? if yes please mark the answer as correct.